# Who is responsible for saving calle-saved registers in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips, calling-convention

When a subroutine is called in MIPS, since the calle-saved registers($s0-$s7) are preserved across function/subroutine calls, they are saved in the subroutine's stack frame if they're going to be modified. Who is responsible for saving them? Am I the assembly programmer responsible for saving these calle-saved registers by writing instructions to store them onto the stack? Or does the assembler somehow manage the saving of calle-saved registers automatically when calling a subroutine for me so they're preserved across calls? I'm just learning MIPS calling conventions so this is entirely new to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function doesn't literally have to save / restore them, you just have to make sure they still have their original value when your function returns.  **The easiest way to do this is to not touch those registers at all.**

Caller vs. callee saved registers is confusing terminology, and incorrectly implies that all registers must be saved somewhere every time there's a function call.

**Much better terminology: call-preserved vs. call-clobbered.**  In both cases you're looking at the registers from the same perspective, as well as not implying that anyone's actually wasting instructions doing any saving.  Just let registers be clobbered if you don't need the value in them after a `jal`.

You can use call-clobbered registers like `$t0..$t9` for whatever you want, and you can return with them holding whatever garbage is left after your code.

If you make a function call inside a loop, you'll probably want to save a couple of the call-preserved registers (`$s0..$s7`) and use one for your loop counter.  Then restore it at the end of your function.  You don't want to store/reload it yourself inside the loop; that would be a big waste if the function you call doesn't touch the register.

Answer (score 1):

You are responsible, the assemblers job is converting what you've written into machine code.

Comment: So, since I'm responsible for everything, there's really nothing inherently different about the $t0-$t9 or $s0 - $s7 registers if I wanted to treat them the same way? For instance, I could save $t0-$t9 and $s0 - $s7 registers onto the stack frame, thereby making $t0-$t9 behave like calle saved registers, despite the fact that they're normally "caller saved/temporary" registers?

Comment: You could indeed. It is worth sticking with conventions usually, that way what you write will play nice with libraries/compiled code, and will be more familiar to people joining the project.

Comment: @Mrcitrusboots exactly, "convention" is just that, convention, and you either respect+support it in your code, or do not, there's nothing HW related inside CPU guarding those conventions. (and both `$s0` and `$t0` are general purpose registers without any extra feature (unlike `$0` and `$sp`, which are inside HW treated a bit differently in some special cases), but most of the 32 MIPS registers are "equal").

Comment: @Colin, Is there a reason for the bias towards `$s0-$s7`? Is it done because it is more optimal?